# NameError: global name 'numpy' is not defined

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a feature extractor by gathering essentia's (a MIR library) functions.
The flow chart is like: individual feature extraction, pool, PoolAggregator, concatenate to form the whole feature list from poolAggregator using `np.concatenate`

**The script runs well under ipython notebook even without importing numpy.** 
I'm just congregating the array or float number I got from the previous stage but the error message: `"NameError: global name 'numpy' is not defined"` shows.

I've tried to put "import numpy as np" at the top of the module:

```
import numpy as np
def featureExtractor(path):
```

or in the function:

```
def featureExtractor(path):
    import numpy as np
```

or outside the module in the main file:

```
import numpy as np
from featureExtractor import featureExtractor
```

None of these can solve it, please help me.

The following is the script:

```
from essentia.standard import *
import essentia

def featureExtractor(path):
    loader = MonoLoader(filename = path)
    x = loader()

    pool = essentia.Pool()
    spectrum = Spectrum()
    w = Windowing(type = 'hann')
    # Create needed objects
    mfcc = MFCC()
    centroid = Centroid()

    for frame in FrameGenerator(x, frameSize = 1024, hopSize = 512):    

        mfcc_bands, mfcc_coeffs = mfcc(spectrum(w(frame))) # output: vector_real
        spec_centroid = centroid(spectrum(w(frame))) # output: real

        pool.add('lowlevel.mfcc', mfcc_coeffs)
        pool.add('lowlevel.centroid', spec_centroid)

    aggrPool = PoolAggregator(defaultStats = [ 'mean', 'var' ])(pool) 
    # calculate mean and var for each feature

    # build a feature vector of type array
    list = ['lowlevel.centroid.mean', 'lowlevel.centroid.var',
            'lowlevel.mfcc.mean', 'lowlevel.mfcc.var']

    feature_vec = []

    for name in list:
        feature = aggrPool[name]
        if type(feature) != float:  # for those type == array
           feature_vec = np.concatenate([feature_vec,feature], axis = 0)
        else: # for those type == float
           feature_vec.append(feature)
    return feature_vec
```

Then I command in the main file:

```
path = "/~/Downloads/~.wav"
from featureExtractor import featureExtractor
featureExtractor(path)
```

I got the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-40b5bbac9b17> in <module>()
      1 from featureExtractor import featureExtractor
      2 
----> 3 featureExtractor(path)

/~/ipython_notebook/featureExtractor.py in featureExtractor(path)
     66         for name in list:
     67                 feature = aggrPool[name]
---> 68         if type(feature) != float:  # for those type == array
     69                 feature_vec = np.concatenate([feature_vec,feature], axis = 0)
     70         else: # for those type == float

NameError: global name 'numpy' is not defined
```

And I got the same error no matter where I put the command (as described in above)

```
import numpy as np
```

Comment: Do you have numpy installed?

Comment: [Strip your file down to the minimum that runs, includes the `import numpy as np` line, and produces the error when you run it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then post what remains. Also, post the complete stack trace your stripped-down code produces. Otherwise, we'll have to look at bits and pieces of your situation and guess at how those pieces fit together.

Comment: @EdChum I run the script directly in ipython notebook and it's fine. The error emerges when I tries to use it as function.

Comment: That could mean your ipython environment has numpy installed but your command line environment does not, if you tried to run a script which just had `import numpy` does this even run? You'll need to install numpy into your python environment

Comment: I just tried to run `import numpy` directly under python prompt and there wasn't any error.

Comment: Do you have ipython notebook in a different virtual environment?

Comment: I also got the error when calling the function in python prompt. But I can import numpy directly, that's weird.

Comment: The stack trace refers to file `featureExtract.py`, but it appears you are editing file `featureExtractor.py`.

Comment: not sure if it is a typo, but I run again and confirm the error. It is `featureExtractor.py`.

Comment: Then it seems you may be adding the `import numpy as np` lines to the wrong file.

Comment: I am sure that I added the line in the correct file `featureExtractor.py`

Comment: That stack trace makes no sense. The line it points to doesn't use the name `numpy` at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try simply

```
import numpy
```

at the top of the file `/~/ipython_notebook/featureExtractor.py`

It seems that your code expect `numpy` and not `np` as the module name.

Comment: If you did not have numpy, you would get a ImportError instead.

Comment: The fact that you can make it work with IPython and not the regular Python interpreter is weird. Do you have a custom installation?

Comment: Also, did you reset IPython's kernel? Else, you may have "leftover" imports.

Comment: Restarting the kernel works! I thought the only thing making difference is the script in module `featureExtractor.py`. I didn't expect restarting kernel to fix the problem! Thank you very much. So I have `import numpy as np` at the top of my module, and it works after restarting the kernel. I thought the only thing that restart does is like `clear all` in Matlab.

Comment: Python (and IPython) do not reload modules without a restart (there are [ways](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.deepreload.html#IPython.lib.deepreload.reload) around it, but it is not practical.

Comment: I thought that re-command the cell could reload the module. I got it, thank you.