# Ipython Notebook: Elegant way of extracting method out?

Tags: python, refactoring, jupyter-notebook

As my notebook gets longer, I want to extract some code out, so the notebook would be easier to read.

For example, this is a `cell/function` that I want to extract from the notebook

```
def R_square_of(MSE, kde_result):
    # R square measure:
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination
    y_mean = np.mean(kde_result)
    SS_tot = np.power(kde_result - y_mean,2)
    SS_tot_avg = np.average(SS_tot)

    SS_res_avg = MSE
    R_square = 1 - SS_res_avg/SS_tot_avg

    return R_square
```

How can I do it effectively?

My thoughts:

1. It's pretty easy to create a `my_helper.py` and put the code above there, then `from my_helper import *`
2. The problem is that, I may use other package in the method (in this case, `np`, i.e. `numpy`), then I need to **re-import** numpy in `my_helper.py`. Can it re-use the environment created in `ipython notebook`, hence no need for re-importing?
3. If I change the code in `my_helper.py`, I need to **restart the kernel** to load the change([NameError: global name 'numpy' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239016/nameerror-global-name-numpy-is-not-defined)), this makes it difficult to change code in that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of importing your other file, you could instead run it with the [%run magic command](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-run):

```
In [1]: %run -i my_helper.py
```

> `-i`: run the file in IPython’s namespace instead of an empty one. This is useful if you are experimenting with code written in a text editor which depends on variables defined interactively.

---

I'd still take the opportunity to recommend writing the file as a proper python module and importing it. This way you actually develop a codebase usable outside of the notebook environment. You could write tests for it or publish it somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I think maybe a module is better, but I need to restart the kernel to commit the change. Is it possible to get rid of that?

Comment: The builtin function [reload](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) may get you some way forward.

Comment: Find this, maybe helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython

Comment: After playing for a while, I think `module` + `autoreload` is the answer.